# Eventhub Connection 1000 Tokens limitation issue when uses StartingEventPostion

Tags: spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

[image]

[image]
Without "starting EventPostion", it was running well.
After adding "startingEventPostion", then it got this error:
*java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.QuotaExceededException: status-code: 403, status-description: The maximum number of '1000' tokens per connection has been reached. ...*

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you pass some more details, what pricing tier you are using for EventHubs and also, how long this job runs before throwing this error?

Comment: Also, i see you are trying to consume only 10 minutes of data, i dont think its a volume issue,

Comment: Thanks for replying. Adding more details here: I use a dedicated Event Hub Cluster, 1024 partitions in Event Hub. When it started "Streaming Initializing", it throw this error immediately....